# Nginx - How to authorize access to repositories using python script

Tags: nginx, python, git, uwsgi, authorization

I have set up a local [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP) server using Nginx ( in Ubuntu ) ,Now  I want to authorize users using external python script , which should authorize them against predefined database .

AFAIK, I have to use [uwsgi](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to link python script with Nginx, however no  examples show how I’m supposed to achieve that.

Any help ?